# In clang-tidy, how to set a check option that accepts at list of numbers

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I am using clang-tidy with a `.clang-tidy` configuration file. The file is read correctly, and I am able to set any kind of check options, except for check options that take a list of numbers as a value.

Here is my `.clang-tidy` file, which attempts to set the check options `modernize-use-nullptr.NullMacros` and `readability-magic-numbers.IgnoredIntegerValues`:

```
Checks: 'modernize-use-nullptr,readability-magic-numbers'
CheckOptions:
  - key:             modernize-use-nullptr.NullMacros
    value:           IT_WORKS_WITH_A_SIMPLE_VALUE
  - key:             readability-magic-numbers.IgnoredIntegerValues
    value:           '5;6;7;8;'
```

When I run clang-tidy with the `--dump-config` option, I get the following result:

```
---
Checks:          'clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*,modernize-use-nullptr,readability-magic-numbers'
WarningsAsErrors: ''
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: false
FormatStyle:     none
User:            user
CheckOptions:
  - key:             cert-dcl16-c.NewSuffixes
    value:           'L;LL;LU;LLU'
  - key:             cert-oop54-cpp.WarnOnlyIfThisHasSuspiciousField
    value:           '0'
  - key:             cppcoreguidelines-explicit-virtual-functions.IgnoreDestructors
    value:           '1'
  - key:             cppcoreguidelines-non-private-member-variables-in-classes.IgnoreClassesWithAllMemberVariablesBeingPublic
    value:           '1'
  - key:             google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines
    value:           '1'
  - key:             google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold
    value:           '800'
  - key:             google-readability-namespace-comments.ShortNamespaceLines
    value:           '10'
  - key:             google-readability-namespace-comments.SpacesBeforeComments
    value:           '2'
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.MaxCopySize
    value:           '16'
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.MinConfidence
    value:           reasonable
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.NamingStyle
    value:           CamelCase
  - key:             modernize-pass-by-value.IncludeStyle
    value:           llvm
  - key:             modernize-replace-auto-ptr.IncludeStyle
    value:           llvm
  - key:             modernize-use-nullptr.NullMacros
    value:           IT_WORKS_WITH_A_SIMPLE_VALUE
  - key:             readability-magic-numbers.IgnoredFloatingPointValues
    value:           '1.0;100.0;'
  - key:             readability-magic-numbers.IgnoredIntegerValues
    value:           '1;2;3;4;'
...
```

As you can see, the `modernize-use-nullptr.NullMacros`
 check option was set correctly, but the `readability-magic-numbers.IgnoredIntegerValues` check option wasn't set.

I think it is probably a problem of syntax, but I use the same syntax as the one given by `--dump-config`, which is supposed to be the right syntax according to clang-tidy documentation.

How can I set the `readability-magic-numbers.IgnoredIntegerValues` check option?

Running `clang-tidy --version` gives the following result:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 9.0.1
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: ivybridge
```

Comment: I tried this in `clang-tidy-10` and had the same problem. However when I try it on the `clang-tidy-11` and the configuration seems to be correct. I was unable to find a specific bug that was fixed: https://reviews.llvm.org/search/query/advanced/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the `--dump-config` for `readability-magic-numbers` check only. Your clang-tidy file works just fine as far as I can tell.

I ran clang-tidy with your .clang-tidy file on this sample code:

```
int badGlobalInt = 5;

int main()
{
    int badLocalInt = 8;
    int unfilteredBadLocalInt = 9;
    return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
N:\xxx>clang-tidy.exe xxx.cpp --
```

The result was just as expected:

```
1 warning generated.
N:\xxx\xxx.cpp:6:30: warning: 9 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
        int unfilteredBadLocalInt = 9;
                                    ^
```

The results were exactly the same for clang-tidy 9 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I use a more JSON-like syntax in my config and it produces the output you see from a subtely different input:

```
- { key: cppcoreguidelines-non-private-member-variables-in-classes.IgnoreClassesWithAllMemberVariablesBeingPublic, value: 1 }
```

Note the comma before value as well as the curly brackets. That gets dumped as

```
- key:             cppcoreguidelines-non-private-member-variables-in-classes.IgnoreClassesWithAllMemberVariablesBeingPublic
  value:           '1'
```

There seems to be some flexibility, and since I have a wide screen long lines with vertical alignment make things easier to read.